# Any .NET ecommerce packages using MVC and Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm trying hard not to go off and roll my own shopping cart, but after perusing the available .NET ecom packages, it's all ASP.NET webforms. In addition, if i see another handrolled DB layer or some manual invocation of Activator.CreateInstance() for extensibility, i'm going to break out in hives.

So what I'm looking for is a shopping cart written in C# using ASP.NET MVC, FubuMVC or Monorail using some Linq capable ORM, preferably NHibernate. I would prefer it to be open source, but if the code base is well done and source license is available, I'm not opposed to a commercial solution.

I know about Rob Conery's webcast series on this topic, but if i'm not rolling my own, i'd like something a little closer to prime time.

Is there such a beast, or is rolling my own the best option?

Comment: Honestly, there aren't any good ones with MVC. I think someone should spear-head this effort though.

Comment: try out [VirtoCommerce](http://virtocommerce.com) enterprise open source product, open source is available at Codeplex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you happen to look at http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/?

This is afaik an open=source e-commerce suite, running ASP.NET MVC and (maybe) Linq2SQL.
It has been deployed at least on one place, and the dude running is (Mike Hadlow at http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/) is supplying with commercial support (I think).

Comment: I had not seen that.. my google skills did not discover it. I will take a closer look

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for an open source ecommerce app that uses MVC then check out http://www.nopcommerce.com - they've just released version 2.0 which is done in MVC 3.

Comment: I need to dig into the new nopCommerce. I worked with the webforms one and it was pretty good. Right now, though I'm using OpenCart because I wanted Quickbooks integration.

Comment: You must have used a version prior to 1.6, because I'm pretty sure nopcommerce has had Quickbooks integration since 1.6. At the very least, I know that 2.0+ has it.

Comment: Yeah, i'd used a prior version and since then had used Intuits partner listing to find quickbooks compatible carts where nopCommerce didn't show up. Looking at nopCommerce again now

Answer (score 2):

iv been developing an ecommerce package using mvc and linq. Its roughly based on magento's implementation and is about 50% complete. All the basic stuff works like adding categories and products, pricing rules, user sign ups, product imports and exports. There are currently two stores using it. Im thinking about open sourcing it and would like to hear from other developers who would be interested in giving me a hand to finish it off.

Comment: Out of curiosity.. why base on Magento?

Comment: For me it’s the best open source e-commerce solution available at the minute, even most licensed software struggles to compete with it. It’s extremely flexible and scalable, clean and simple design and has more features than any other shopping cart I’ve seen. I would like to see something similar on a Microsoft stack hence this project.

Comment: ..I would like you to consider sharing your code with me as I would be interested in working with you and helping you out finishing it off. filippono (at) hotn-ail.commmm. Let me know

Comment: ..just to confirm, your MVC implementation is the Asp.NET MVC one, yes?

Comment: yes its in asp.net MVC2. Its been a while since I worked on this project but I am going to dig it out and do some tidy ups then probably release it on codeplex. anyone else interested in working on it please reply here or email me conaire.creaney (at) g mail .com

Answer (score 1):

Me and my team created a product called [VirtoCommerce](http://virtocommerce.com) which is a .NET product implemented using MVC4/Razor, utilizes IoC (Unity), EF5, Repository model and many more common sense development practices. It also designed to work and scale on Windows Azure, meaning it uses queues, blobs to distribute work as needed. We also recently made it open source which is available on codeplex. We run couple of sites on them with more than 2.5 million page views per day and thousands of orders per day.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look on microsoft web platform web app library. There is ecommerce section there http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/categories.aspx?category=eCommerce
All aps is free